# Formatting index page references as "1 sq." without "sq." being part of a hyperlink

Tags: hyperref, formatting, indexing

By default, MakeIndex will format page references which are composed of two or three consecutive pages as (e.g.) "1, 2"/"1-3". With a suitable index style file, the formatting can be changed to "1 sq."/"1 sqq." (with "sq." standing for "sequens", "sqq." for "sequentes"). However, with the [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) package loaded, "sq." and "sqq." will be part of the respective page reference hyperlinks. How can I limit those hyperlinks to the actual page numbers?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
suffix_2p "~sq."
suffix_3p "~sqq."
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text about foo\index{foo}.

\clearpage

Another text about foo\index{foo}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for explaining what `sq` and `sqq` stand for. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to my question can be found in `hyperref`'s README (not in the manual):

> For hyperlink support in the index, `hyperref` inserts `\hyperpage`
>   into the index macros. After processing with Makeindex, `\hyperpage`
>   analyzes its argument to detect page ranges and page comma lists.
>   However, only the standard settings are supported directly:
>
> ```
> delim_r "--"
> delim_n ", "
> ```
>
> (See manual page/documentation of Makeindex that explains the keys
>   that can be used in style files for Makeindex.) Customized versions of
>
> ```
> delim_r, delim_n, suffix_2p, suffix_3p, suffix_mp
> ```
>
> needs markup that `\hyperpage` can detect and knows that this stuff
>   does not belong to a page number. Makro `\nohyperpage` serves as this
>   markup. Put the customized code for these keys inside `\nohyperpage`,
>   e.g.:
>
> ```
> suffix_2p "\\nohyperpage{f.}"
> suffix_3p "\\nohyperpage{ff.}"
> ```
>
> (Depending on the typesetting tradition some space "`\\,`" or "~" should
>   be put before the first f inside `\nohyperpage`.)

In my case, the index style file must be modifield as follows:

```
suffix_2p "\\nohyperpage{~sq.}"
suffix_3p "\\nohyperpage{~sqq.}"
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Using hyperref you can also manipulate the grouping mechanism.

Using makeindex means that the complete page number is formated with `\command{...}`

So you can simple add a `}{` to your suffix declaration:

```
suffix_2p "}{~sq."
```

Here the complete code (I used `imakeidx` to simplify the compilation)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.mst}
suffix_2p "}{~sq."
suffix_3p "~sqq."
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

Some text about foo\index{foo}.

\clearpage

Another text about foo\index{foo}.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice trick! Could there be any adverse effects?

Comment: @lockstep: As long as you using `makeindex` no. The trick is the same. To format the page of a special index entry you can use `\index{foo|textbf}`. That shows you can use every command with one mandatory argument. So the opening and closing is one way.